# Specifying phyiscal size in CSS (e.g. 2 inches) when printing a web page

Tags: html, css, printing

Is there a reliable way to specify physical dimensions in CSS such that when the page is printed, my elements are at a specific size and position on the printed page?

I see that CSS has units for in and cm, but (not surprisingly) neither Firefox nor Chrome actually printed the box at 2x2 inches when I did the following:

```
.test {
    width: 2in;
    height: 2in;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
```

Am I being too optimistic hoping that there is some way of specifying the size and having the browser adjust it's printing size based on the resolution of the printer etc?

Thanks.

Comment: How much did the output did it deviate? The physical units should work exactly as you expect. aLthough it seems to be used mostly for margins

Comment: The best way to print HTML and CSS is with a PDF. There's several decent to good libraries out there, include [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) for PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I had forgotten to remove a reference to another stylesheet which must have been responsible for the extra padding. It's now spot on in Firefox, and about 1/2cm too large in Chrome (but this will do fine for now). 

Jared - I think you're probably right, PDF seems a safer bet - I'll give this a try. Does anyone know of any good (ideally free) .NET libraries for this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `margin: 0; padding: 0` to avoid any extra spacing.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - I feel silly now - I had forgotten to remove reference to one of my other stylesheets so there must have been something somewhere adding padding. With no additional styles, and margin and padding set to 0 I get exactly 2 inches in Firefox.

Comment: Padding may of course affect the dimensions (and margin, and border, depending on how you measure them), but even if they are eliminated, the actual accuracy still varies by browser and by printer – small deviations are common.

Answer (score 6):

In theory, by the CSS3 Values and Units Module Level 3, clause [5.2. Absolute lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths), the `cm` unit should match the physical centimeter on “print media and similar high-resolution devices”, whereas on lower-resolution devices, the pixel should be the anchor unit, which normally means that `cm` differs from the physical unit.

In practice, it’s even worse. I just tested with an element set to be `15cm` wide. On screen (including Print Preview) it’s actually 15.8cm, and when printed on a physical printer, it’s 14.7cm (so it’s essentially closer, but still far from exact).

Comment: A printer has in its PPD file defined an imageable region because printers usually cannot print completely to the edge of the paper. The print system may check that your content is completely inside that box or scale it so that it is. On a mac this appears as a scale % lower than 100% but you can manually enter 100% and avoid this.